# How to return content in <head> through a wordpress API endpoint

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, wordpress-rest-api

So I've been trying to extend the Wordpress API to fetch the content which Wordpress outputs in the `<head>`.

I've registered my endpoint like so in `functions.php` of my theme:

```
add_action('rest_api_init', function () {
  register_rest_route( 'hs/v1', 'header',array(
                'methods'  => 'GET',
                'callback' => 'get_head_content'
      ));
});
```

And the callback looks like below but only returns empty arrays for each key:

```
function get_head_content() {

    $result = [];
    $result['scripts'] = [];
    $result['styles'] = [];

    // Print all loaded Scripts
    global $wp_scripts;
    foreach( $wp_scripts->queue as $script ) :
       $result['scripts'][] =  $wp_scripts->registered[$script]->src . ";";
    endforeach;

    // Print all loaded Styles (CSS)
    global $wp_styles;
    foreach( $wp_styles->queue as $style ) :
       $result['styles'][] =  $wp_styles->registered[$style]->src . ";";
    endforeach;

    return $result;
}
```

So my guess is that the `get_head_content` returns nothing since nothing has been enqueued because I'm not actually triggering the queue by hitting the API endpoint. This doesn't really output the whole `<head>` as a string either which would be my main objective.

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the output buffer and get_header:

```
function get_head_content() {
    ob_start();
    get_header();
    $header = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();

    return $header ;
}
```